# Given n apples with known weights. Your task is to distribute apples among 2 groups such that the difference between weights of the groups is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Constraints:

1 <= n <= 20

1 <= Weight of apples <= 10^9

I know that I can take all combinations considered the constraint for n is low. But I did not want to do that, so I came up with a solution that I thought would potentially solve the problem. My approach is: Give all apples to one group, say B. Then at each iteration choose one apple I from B and give it group A such that choosing I minimizes the difference in resulting weights. I continue until the weight of group A becomes greater. This approach did not yield an optimal solution. But I did not get what I'd miss even after looking at a failed testcase.

The testcase was: n=10; Weights={952 775 292 702 859 719 65 943 376 490}
Ans: 1(the difference between groups after distributing apples optimally)

Test case 2: n=5; Weights={3 2 7 4 1}
Ans: 1 => the only test case among 10 others I got accepted =)

```
def min_diff(n, w: list):
    total_sum = sum(w)
    group_a = 0
    group_b = total_sum
    greedy_diff = total_sum + 1
    curr_diff = total_sum
    chosen = [False] * n
    j = None

    while group_a < group_b:
        for i in range(n):
            if not chosen[i]:
                diff = abs((group_a + w[i]) - (group_b - w[i]))
                if curr_diff > diff:
                    curr_diff = diff
                    j = i
        if greedy_diff > curr_diff:
            greedy_diff = curr_diff
            chosen[j] = True
            group_a += w[j]
            group_b = group_b - w[j]
    return greedy_diff
```

What I need to know is what did I miss? Why won't this greedy method work? Does this even have a greedy solution?

Comment: This problem is known as the [Subset Sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: The problem is called "subset sum" which is NP-HARD, and it can't be solved by a greedy algorithm.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "why won't this greedy method work" because you apparently have an example for which it produces the wrong result. Look at the choices it makes when you run it on that example, and find the first one that is wrong. Then that is an instance of a mistake it makes. If you have an idea why you think the algorithm is correct, reconcile that idea with the mistake you see it making.

Comment: Note that your algorithm often doesn't terminate at all. For example, `min_diff([1, 6])`

Comment: If you fix the termination problem and return the best-found-so-far solution when you don't make progress, , `[5, 1, 4, 2, 6]` is the smallest case I found where your algorithm goes wrong. It chooses 6 first, but then 4 and stops. Choosing 4 is a mistake because the optimal solution is 6+2+1.

Comment: A powerful debug method (that I used here) is to write an oracle function -- an inefficient but obviously correct solution -- and then generate small random test cases until you find one where your code and the optimal code differ. My oracle was as simple as possible -- it evaluates every possible subset for a and returns the best one.

Comment: Here is my code that fixes your termination problem, and then finds breaking test-cases: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/2d8323b8ab8e7ae2fa80e2e5ba7afff4 . Adjust N and L to search for longer examples (N) and ones with larger numbers (L).